# change instagram bio results in TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api

I am trying to make a bio generator to generate a new one for my account.
I am using the `instagram_private_api` library and `edit_profile` fiction.

For some time I try to change the bio and I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I tried to replace my data with data I found on the web, and still got the same error.

Python version: `3.10.5`

### code:

```
import os
import asyncio
from spotify import worker
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch

user_name = os.getenv('INSTA_USR')
password = os.getenv('INSTA_PASS')

const_bio = " Student at the Hebrew University of Jerusalem.\nL293D\n"

api = Client(user_name, password)
results = api.username_info(user_name)
user_info = results['user']

async def activate_worker():
    async for result in worker():
        new_bio = const_bio + result
        api.edit_profile('דוד',
                         str(new_bio),
                         'https://github.com/David-hosting',
                         '************@gmail.com',
                         "+************",
                         1)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    asyncio.run(activate_worker())
```